# Can ARP expire mid iperf connection?

Tags: arp, iperf

If one runs an iperf connection between a node 'A' and a node 'B' is it possible that the arp entry expires from one of the nodes. [I have a simple mininet topology and while running an iperf connection between two hosts -- one of the arp expires -- Can be checked using wireshark!]. My main question is why does arp expire mid connection. Isn't the arp entry supposed to expire when the entry is idle?

Comment: Yes, the timers of the neighbour cache should be rewinded by active connections. Not sure what can cause this to fail.

Comment: ARP expires where? One of the nodes? Are they on the same subnet?

Comment: The nodes are on the same subnet. A has the entry of B and B has the entry for A. B is the server while A is the client and entry of A on B expires.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely not.  An arp cache entry doesn't get deleted if the network stack deems it as being referenced, so even a stale entry won't "fail" from a packet sending/forwarding perspective and will remain in the ip neighbor cache.  The traffic itself has to go idle for a period of time before neighbor cache entries are removed.